# player on the Wowza server?

Tags: wowza

if we will stream from Wowza 3.5 enabled to reach also the Androids, do its enough to upload this HTML5 player on our server, OR it should be downloaded by all Android users ?
Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to place html5 player on the server but don't forget that some android devices couldn't play or show html5 players.